# Classification in ENVI

Tags: classification, spatial-statistics, envi, image-classification

I classified multiple images using ENVI modeler and I would like class statistics for each image. Is there a task available in ENVI modeler that can do this? I know I can right click each image and get the stats that way but I want a more automatic way to achieve this.

Comment: As per the [Tour], there should be "One question per Question". If you add "Also," and another question to your Question it is likely to be closed as lacking *focus*.